# Is there a way to find a table in a DBML file in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql, dbml

This ones been bugging me for ages.

Back in the olden days when we hunted our own food and used DataSets, you could snap to a particular table in a DataSet by selecting what you want from a drop down list at the top.

If I have a big ol' Linq2Sql DBML file with lots of tables in it, it becomes a nightmare to navigate around. Is there a way to jump to a particular table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find (search for) table in DBML designer quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920014/find-search-for-table-in-dbml-designer-quickly)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have your "Properties" View turned on, theres a DropDown at the top that you can select your DBML Entities from, and the canvas should snap focus to the particular entity when you select it

Comment: Absolutely spankingly brilliant

Comment: I agree... this is absolutely wonderful! Been struggling with this for ages!

Comment: Logged in just to vote this answer up . It was a nightmare for me with a dbml of 150 tables. Thanks.

Comment: Wish I could have found this a while ago - I was always wondering how people got around in the beast that is a DBML - and now I know and can apply that method to save myself time!

Comment: open dbml properties; select target table from drop-down; click on designer tab to give focus; use cursor arrow keys to move the selected target so that it can be discerned against the rest of the mess

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip. I can't wait to tell my colleague who says this is not possible!