# Find (search for) table in DBML designer quickly?

Tags: visual-studio, search, linq-to-sql

We have a design with 150+ tables and in the .dbml layout has lines everywhere and it's hard to find individual tables.

Is there a way to search in the dbml layout instead of scrolling around trying to locate a table (Ctrl+F don't work), Running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

One thing you can do is go to the `Properties` window (while you have your DBML file open), and select the class generated for the table you're interested in from the dropdown list at the top of the `Properties` window.

[image]

Doing so should focus the DBML file visual designer on that table corresponding to that class. Doesn't work always, but it's quite helpful when it does work!